# RXJS combine/merge two Observable array by an propety "id"

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

i have two Observable

```
chat$: Observable<Chat[]>;
users$: Observable<User[]>;
```

where Chat is:

```
export interface Chat {
   user_id: string;
   message: string;
}
```

and User is:

```
export interface User  {
   user_id: string;
   username: string;
}
```

Now i wanto combine the two oservable in a new one, eg.:

```
threads$: Observable<Thread[]>;
```

where Threadis:

```
export interface Chat {
   user_id: string;
   username: string;
   message: string;
}
```

i have tried with a merge and a spaghetti code into map, eg:

```
threads$ = Observable.merge(chat$, users$).pipe( map( ??? ) );
```

but doesn't works... i'm a newbie on rxjs.

How combine the two array using the "user_id" property?

Comment: So you want to get all emissions from both Observables and then combine them?

Comment: so your observables are emitting _arrays_ of users and chats?  And, on each emission of either source, just combine the 2 arrays into an array of threads?  If that is what you want, just use `combineLatest()`.  Otherwise you may need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Take this answer as pseudocode because i did it on my phone

```
import {concatMap, toArray} from 'rxjs/operators';
import  {map, concat} from 'rxjs';

const fullMessage$ = (message) =>
    this.user$.get(message.user_id)
        .pipe(
            map( user => ({...message, name: user.name}))
        )

this.chat$
    .pipe(
        concatMap( (messages: Chat[]) =>
            concat(...messages.map(fullMessage$))
            )
        toArray()
        )
```

Comment: Dont't forget to subscribe